# C++ need find symbol from array

Tags: c++, if-statement, symbols

I need to create a program that searches how many comments (`//` symbols) are in .txt file.

This is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const char read[] = "read.txt";
const char result[] = "result.txt";
const int CMax = 256;

void Skaityti (char E[], int& n);

int main() {
  char E[CMax];
  int n,k;
  Skaityti(E,n);
  ofstream rs(result);
  rs << k;
  return 0;
}

void Skaityti (char E[], int & n)
{
  ifstream fd(read);
  int k;
  char sim = '/';
  for (n = 0; !fd.eof() && n < n+1; n++)
       fd.get(E[n]);
       for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {
       if(sim == E[n])
       k++; }
   fd.close();
}
```

Program read fine, but I can't get symbol from massive.

Comment: What is a "massive", and what does it have to do with the code you posted?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the text you are trying to parse, the results you are expecting, and the results you get.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Don't you have a massive? I do. It's a very lovely massive!

Comment: My mistake, I had on mind arrays.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question... but I think you're asking to see how many times "//" appears in a file. I threw this together:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int Skaityti()
{
    ifstream fd("test.txt");
    int count = 0;

    while(fd.good())
    {
        char c = fd.get();
        if(fd.good())
            if(c == '/')
            {
                c = fd.get();
                if(fd.good())
                    if(c == '/')
                        count++;    // At this point we have two comments in a row
        }
    }

    fd.close();

    return count;
}
```